# MVC Codeigniter - How is the controller called from the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm still new to mvc, working on a project using the codeigniter framework. I have searched through a lot of tutorials and stackoverflow posts and I still cannot find a simple answer to a very simple question. How is the the controller called from the views. Is it just an ajax call from every view page and POST the required controller url?

I understand the concept of mvc but just cannot figure out the best way to call a controller based on selecting something on the view. Maybe it is just a simple ajax call and I'm overthinking it but a some clarification on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Example:

I have a form view loaded. When the user select the 'next' button on the form I want the controller to be called that loads the next view after the form. Do you just trigger a POST to the controller url when the button is clicked? That is my question. Maybe that is the way to do it but it hasn't been clarified anywhere i've read.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish or where your understanding is breaking down. Could you please expand your question to explain what, concretely, you are trying to do, and what you have tried so far that has failed to accomplish that? Without that it is very hard to know what a helpful answer would be.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut right now I am still learning the pattern. I understand how certain controllers and their methods are called and parsed through the  URL. Let's say on a certain form view when the user clicked on the 'next' button i wanted it to call the controller the loaded the next part of the form. How is that controller called? Again maybe it's just a POST to load that URL and i am overthinking it.

Comment: This chart might help visualize what is going on with each request: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/appflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned earlier you don't call a controller from the view normally. That goes against MVC. What you can do, if I am getting your question right, you can add a URL that points to your controller as a value to your select option tag. Than you can handle the selection from javascript as an onselect event. You just give the selected value to window.location.href and you will be redirected to your controller.

Comment: Thank you. You are getting closer to the point of my confusion. If you do not call the controller from the view then how are controller loaded. Based on the flow of the application how are certain controllers loaded? Obviously you do not expect the user to enter the the controller url. So how is it called?

Comment: When you generate your view, you will have to assign all the controllers you wish to offer for the user to your option tag's value attribute. It's pretty much the same when you link to a page on your website. But it this case you do not link to a certain html or php file; you just link to your controller and the routing mechanism will handle the request.

Comment: okay. So you are just loading the controller url based on user selection? And this is the proper way to do it in mvc?

Comment: Yes, it is. To make it easier to understand, think about HTTP. It is a request-response protocoll. Once your view has been generated, the response will be sent to the user. The next time he will interact with your code will be when he clicks your link pointing at your controller.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. You really clarified mvc concepts for me.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is actually the `routing` structure, this dictates how the controllers load up the views depending on a specific URL request.

Say you have this url: `example.com/products`

This will look for a controller with a class of `Products`. Also, it will default look for a function called `index` within the controller by default. We will also want to pull down all of the products from our `products` table, so we'll need to have our associated model. let's have a look at what that looks like:

```
class Products extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        //load our Products model
        $this->load->model('Model_products');

        //let's get all of our products off of our model
        $data['products'] = $this->Products->all();

        //now let's return all of our products with our view `products`
        $this->load->view('products', $data);
    }
}
```

Of course we need our associated model in `application/models/products_model.php`, with an `all` function that retrieves all `products` from the database.

```
class Products_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct():
    }

    public function all(){
        return $this->db->get('products');
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps give you some clarity on how the MVC pattern works with `internal routing`.

Comment: I appreciate the example. I get how the routing works and how the view is loaded. My question is how is the controller loaded. The user is not going to manually enter every single controller url. Based on certain user inputs on certain vies how do you load other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mvc standards, views shouldn't access controllers methods directly. If you want to bring another class method result to your view, you should call it inside your controller and store it in a variable, so you can access it inside the view.

Example using code igniter:

```
//controller:
$data = array(
    'name' => 'Carlos',
);
$this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

and then:

```
//view
echo $name; //prints 'Carlos'
```

Comment: Yes, so this is loading the view from the controller. How is the controller called or loaded from the view. Let's say based on a certain select on the view I want to call another controller to load a different view, how do I load that controller?